# How to configure components for a master detail MYSQL structure

Tags: mysql, delphi-2007

I have two database tables that one is the master one and the other one the Detail table.
I use dbexpress SQLQuery component for Master table, a Datasetprovider & a clientdataset. I checked Autorefresh, Cascade Deletes, Cascade Updates for the Datasetprovider of the Master Table. I also set on the updateData event of the Datasetprovider all the fields of the Master Table with the flag "pfInUpdate" 
apart from the key field that I also set "pfInKey" & "pfInWhere" flags.

```
SQLQuery1.Active:=true;
SQLQuery1.sql.Clear;
SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('select table1.*,');
SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('table2.AKRO_B_ID,table2.AKRO_B_EETT,table2.AKRO_B,
...');
SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(' from PATH1 as table1');
SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('left join PATH2 as table2 ON 
(table1.LINK_ID =   table2.LINK_ID)');
ClientDataset1.Active:=True;
ClientDataset1.Open;
ClientDataset1.LogChanges:=True;
Datasource1.Enabled:=True;
```

I use dbexpress SQLDataset component for Detail table,  a Datasetprovider & a clientdataset.
I use the following syntax on the Create Event of the main form for Detail Table Components:

```
SQLDataSet1.CommandText:='SELECT * FROM PATH2 WHERE LINK_ID=LINK_ID'; 
ClientDataset2.Mastersource:=DataSource1;     
ClientDataset2.MasterFields:='LINK_ID';      
ClientDataset2.IndexFieldNames:='LINK_ID';    
SQLDataSet1.Active:=TRUE;
SQLDataSet1.Open;
ClientDataset2.Active:=True;
ClientDataset2.Open;
ClientDataset2.LogChanges:=True;
Datasource2.Enabled:=true;
```

The problem is that when I made a change on the Master Table the Post event works fine but when I made a change on the fields of the Detail table that does not work and the detail table remains unchanged. It seems also that the insert command doesn't have any effect on the two Database tables. Hence what is the right way to configure all the components in order the master detail structure to work fine?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952217/how-to-configure-components-for-a-master-detail-mysql-structure) or the [documentation using parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Establishing_Master-detail_Relationships_Using_Parameters)/[using `t(sql)table`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships). Important: in any case, you don't need the `join` in your query. That is was is simulated with the `mastersource`-link.

Comment: As I already mentioned I try to use the model SQLQuery, Datasetprovider & Clientdataset. The link that you provided me doesn't refer to that structure.

Comment: Have you tried it? A clientdataset is, as the name implies, an descendant from a dataset, so it works the same, it's just stored mainly in memory. The important thing is: you cannot use a join in your query (well, you can, but then you have to use custom updates in your datasetprovider, and it doesn't create the child, just a bigger master). Master and child are seperate "Tables"/"Queries" with their own data, then you connect that data by using the mastersource/link. The link will take care of filtering the required data inside the child table.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I 'll try your advice.